# Смена цвета текста при скролле

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

У меня есть `header`.

Изначально все слова в нем черного цвета, но при скролле цвет должен меняться, как это можно сделать, есть может какие-то готовые решения?
Есть такая верстка, но отображается она плохо, т.к. она на бутстрапе.

```css
.header_area {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0 4%;
}

.menu_area .navbar-brand {
  font-size: 72px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu_area .navbar-brand:hover,
.menu_area .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #fff;
}

.menu_area {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.menu_area #nav .nav-link {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 30px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
  -o-transition-duration: 500ms;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
  padding: 35px 15px;
}

.menu_area nav ul li>a:hover {
  color: #fb397d;
}

.header_area.sticky {
  background: rgb(0, 122, 223);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(77deg, rgb(0, 122, 223) 0%, rgb(0, 236, 188) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(77deg, rgb(0, 122, 223) 0%, rgb(0, 236, 188) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(77deg, rgb(0, 122, 223) 0%, rgb(0, 236, 188) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(77deg, rgb(0, 122, 223) 0%, rgb(0, 236, 188) 100%);
  height: 70px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}

.header_area.sticky .menu_area .navbar-brand {
  font-size: 50px;
}

.header_area.sticky .menu_area #nav .nav-link {
  padding: 23px 15px;
}

.header_area.sticky .navbar {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<header class="header_area animated">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-12 col-lg-10">
        <div class="menu_area">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
              <img src="img/image.png" style="margin-top: -15px;width: 48px; height: 38px;">
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ca-navbar" aria-controls="ca-navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="ca-navbar">
              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" id="nav" style="margin-right: -220px;">
                <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#home" style="color: #000;">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#about" style="color: #000;">About</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#features" style="color: #000;"></a>Text</li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#application" style="color: #000;">Application</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#support" style="color: #000;">Support</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#contact" style="color: #000;">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Как сделать, чтобы при скролле вниз текст был белым и картинка тоже, т.е чтобы фактически картинка заменялась с черной на белую?

Comment: На Bootstrap он должен, точнее обязан отражаться нормально.... Не совсем понятно, вы хотите чтоб все работало на Bootstrap, или же переделать без него?

Comment: @на нем, просто его скинуть не могу, большой слишком

Comment: А зачем его скидывать? Все знают что такое Bootstrap. Вам JS нужен будет немного. Я пока-что занят до вечера, если никто не ответит, я вам вкратце расскажу, что и как делать.

Comment: @VladSpirin, окей, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Это всего лишь пример.  Смысл в том, что при скролле, элемент `header_area`
 получает новый класс. А в `css` уже данному классу задаются нужные правила.

```js
//document.querySelector('.header_area') так мы хватаем нужный элемент ('.header_area') в скобках может быть любой другой нужный элемент

//document.body.onscroll = function(){} это функция в которой все происходит, что (грубо говоря) в нее засунешь, то и отработает при скролле.




document.body.onscroll = function() {
  document.querySelector('.header_area').classList.add('green')
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}

.header_area {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<header class="header_area animated">

</header>
```

Comment: у меня изначально цвет слов черный, после скролла они становятся белыми. а тут бэкграунд просто изначально другой цвет сделан. как только цвет слов изменить при скролле? например как тут: https://colorlib.com/preview/#massive Изначально header сливается и текст белый а после скролла нужен черный например. просто не знаю как реализовать

Comment: @Juicy134, написал маленькое пояснения в ответе... Если ты вообще не знаком с `JS`,то уж прости, тут за тебя ни кто не будет писать так как тебе надо, а если хотя бы чуть-чуть есть познание в `JS`то из примера можно понять как и что